# Is it easier to get a user to watch a video, or to scroll?

Tags: website-design, homepage, video, marketing

I see a lot of startups using product videos as the primary focus on their home page, with cheeky animated characters explaining whatever their product might be. But is there any data showing whether or not people actually watch these videos, or whether users engage better with written content instead?

My guess is that well worded explanations with supporting imagery that a user can scroll or engage through would perform better (especially on things like mobile...) than a video would, but I don't have any hard evidence to support this. It's just sort of my gut feeling.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I think you should conduct an A/B test and report back with the results. :)

Comment: Any suggestion for a tool to use for that?

Comment: As a user, I normally read the text below the video and if it interests me enough then I'll watch the video. For example Kickstarter does it great. They show a video of a product and then details under it. So I would suggest both.

Comment: You should offer both. For the reasons @mtsyganov gives, but also because people differ in the way they like to ingest information. Some prefer watching a video, others prefer reading. If you pick just one, you stand to lose a significant part of your potential public.

Comment: Personally, I *hate* videos that do not have a detailed summary of the content or story below or at least linked

Comment: I can't suggest a tool without knowing what your goals in having people watch a video or read information are.  If this is just a generic question and you're not actually designing for something, then the information below from Mervin is a good starting point.

Answer (score 7):

You should offer both. For people who dont have patience to watch 60 sec long movie, will simply scroll the page down and look at screenshots with feature visualization. If that persons get interest in your project, they will take time to watch the movie to get the full explanation of you product. 
On the other side there are people who are typical TV watchers. Those people will click on play button and watch your movie directly.
Perfect solution in my eyes is apple.com

Comment: Downvoted because the original poster asked for hard evidence.

Comment: *"I don't have any hard evidence...What do you guys **think**?"*

Answer (score 3):

As mtsyganov suggested offering both can help users in making an informed decision, studies have shown that product videos do help in conversion.I recommend looking at [this article which talks about a number of case studies of how product videos have increased conversion greatly](https://econsultancy.com/blog/61817-six-retailers-that-used-product-videos-to-improve-conversion-rates). To quote part of the article

> **Zappos**
>
> Zappos uses videos on a huge number of its product pages, and was one
>   of the original success stories in this area.
>
> It found that sales increased by between 6% and 30% for items that
>   included product demos.
>
> [image]
>
> **Simply Piste**
>
> Ski equipment retailer Simply Piste used videos to demonstrate
>   products to shoppers. This video showed how much the backpack can
>   carry, the number of pockets, zips, etc.
>
> As a result Simply Piste saw conversion rates increase by 25% on pages
>   that included video.
>
> [image]

I also recommend looking at this post [Videos for Landing Pages 101](http://blog.landerapp.com/make-the-difference-with-video-landing-pages/) which talks about how videos can assist in conversion and which type  of videos convert best. To quote the article

> A [recent research report by Invodo](http://www2.invodo.com/l/12102/2013-02-06/7c6wq) said that 52% of consumers say
>   that watching a product video makes them more confident in online
>   purchase decisions, and another 52% said they are less likely to
>   return a product they have purchased after watching a video. Treepodia
>   says that [video increases](http://conversionxl.com/how-to-use-video-to-increase-conversions/) conversion rates, from 14% increase for
>   electronics to 113% for gifts.

The article also has to say about the type of video which converts best

> How do you know which video format is best for you? Brian Massey, the
>   Conversion Scientist, has the answer. In a study conducted to measure
>   the conversion results of different video formats, Massey found that
>   [talking head videos drove conversion rates of 3.2%](http://conversionscientist.com/video-that-converts/does-higher-engagement-mean-higher-conversion-rates/) vs. screen
>   capture of slides at a measly 1.6% conversion.